# SSRS 2017 reports loading slow with Intranet connection and loading immediately with Internet connection from web link

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have created SSRS reports and Query which i am using in particular SSRS report is fetching data immediately.when i try to run any report first time it is taking more time when i run the same report 2nd or 3 rd time it is loading immediately and when i run same report for the first time in report builder it is loading immediately and when i open same report with system which is having internet connection it is loading immediately and when i try to open same report with LAN/Intranet connection it is routing to **az416426.vo.msecnd.net**. once az416426.vo.msecnd.net link is time out then it routing to my SSRS report and loading the data.How to stop routing to az416426.vo.msecnd.net and how to fix it.is there any thing i need to add in settings or anything wrong with my SSRS reports.with inetrnet connection report is loading in 5-10 seconds and same report with Intranet it is taking 40-50 seconds.I read in some of the articles we need to change Recycletime in rsreportserver.config file. i tried this option as well but it didn't worked for me. please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Venkateswara rao

Comment: Venkateswara, some details are missing from your description. For example it would be relevant to know if the SSRS and SQL Server are running on the same instance or not? 
How big is your result set? Does the first run take 10 seconds or 1 hour? Is your SQL Server super busy or does have enough RAM?
Does it happen throughout the day, all day?
There are at least 3 level of caching within what you describe. SQL Server caches query results, SSRS Data sources can cache data and reports itself can be cached in SSRS. On a busy SQL Server it is quite normal that the first query exec takes longer

Comment: @MojoDBA, adding that SQL Server caches data pages rather than query results. The first execution of the query will read the needed pages into the buffer cache and subsequent executions will use cached pages instead of re-reading from storage (if still in cache), avoiding costly IO. The additional SSRS caching you mentioned will also explain the symptoms.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Dan, I misspoke.